# node.js serve a wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, node.js, webserver

I am using node.js on my rackspace server to serve my various applications. (Using node-http-proxy).

However, i would like to start a wordpress blog. The only way to serve the blog is via apache (or nginx).

Is there a way to server my wordpress blog from a node.js application itself?

Comment: lol. Wordpress has a static mode, right? How about you use Wordpress to publish static files to disk and serve those with Node?

Comment: were you talking about this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/static-html-output-plugin/ ? :)

Comment: This page has old answers; I've [added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58597865/199364) that links to Automattic's more recent "official" solution to this; a github repo [wpcom.js](https://github.com/Automattic/wpcom.js), that calls the WordPress REST API. Apologies for promoting my own answer; but IMHO this supersedes the outdated existing answers.

Answer (score 5):

You need some server running to execute the PHP. Node is JavaScript.

Whether that's apache, or nginx/php-fpm or just php-fpm, you need something to actually run the wordpress code, then use the same proxying system you are using now.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to continue to use Wordpress as you normally do, but instead of writing the templates to output HTML, you make them output JSON. With this minor trick, you suddenly have created your own API to output your wordpress content. In contrast with the modules that expose wordpress complete set of methods, this will create your very specific output, tailored after your needs.

To consume your JSON output, you set up a small nodejs server that forwards each call directly to your Wordpress solution, takes the response (JSON) and merges it with your html using whatever javascript template engine you like. You also gain speed, since you can cache the JSON result pretty easily on the node side, and control.

I've written a blogpost about this if you like to read more, and also created a nodejs express middleware to help setting up the node side.

http://www.1001.io/improve-wordpress-with-nodejs/

Comment: I like this idea. Though you could just as easily have it output just the HTML for the post itself, and then inject that HTML into your templates.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [express-php-fpm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-php-fpm) package.

It combines Express (Node.js server) and FastCGI gateway to serve php requests.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I made some changes to make it work better with WordPress: https://github.com/steffanhalv/servewp

Answer (score 1):

I found this node module while searching for Wordpress + Node:

https://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-wordpress

I haven't tried it, though, but if you know what you're doing you might want to give it a go.

Comment: wouah its been ages since. I guess node-wordpress had done the job then. If you wanna use node, i'd recommend you try [ghost](https://ghost.org/) though.
if you use node-wordpress.. to tell me so that I pick this as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to get a server within an electron app to serve PHP.
I started with [grunt-php](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-php) by Sindre Sorhus. The main change I made was to remove the code that kills the server process when grunt is done, instead instantiating the PHP class from JS and calling the process as needed.
Ultimately, it was very easy to adapt grunt-php to enable PHP on a node.js server.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress now has an "official" (to be precise: open source, under Automattic's github repo) way to do this: [wpcom.js](https://github.com/Automattic/wpcom.js). From that github page:

> Official JavaScript library for the WordPress.com REST API. Compatible with Node.js and web browsers.

The essence is to call the [WordPress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/) from JS.