# Node forward path request to another server

Tags: node.js, express, routes, request

Currently have a website running a node server that handles all requests for `example.com` and I created a completely separate wordpress blog on a separate server (running apache) that I would like served on a path like `example.com/blog` at `172.23.23.23` IP address. The wordpress server doesn't share any code or is even aware of the existence of anything besides itself

What is the best way in node/express to forward all requests in this manner? Also what should the A/CNAME records for the new wordpress server point to?

Comment: Checkout [node.js serve a wordpress blog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810323/node-js-serve-a-wordpress-blog)

Comment: Interesting I didn't know that existed, but not really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This works: here's what you need to put in your node app:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();

var proxy = require('http-proxy').createProxyServer({
    host: 'http://your_blog.com',
    // port: 80
});
app.use('/blog', function(req, res, next) {
    proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: 'http://your_blog.com'
    }, next);
});

app.listen(80, function(){
    console.log('Listening!');
});
```

Then in your wordpress app you need to set the Site URL to `http://your_node_app.com/blog`

Note: You probably already have an express app with probably a [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware which [causes errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632854/socket-hangup-while-posting-request-to-node-http-proxy-node-js) and [generally doesn't play well with POST requests in http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/180#issuecomment-3996256)

You'll find couple solutions in those threads, namely 1: just put this proxy *before* body-parser, or 2: use [connect-restreamer](https://github.com/dominictarr/connect-restreamer)

Comment: using your, @laggingreflex, suggestion, I have this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736094/node-js-proxy-unable-to-load-first-certificate

Comment: @laggingreflex, How to read the response status code and response body of proxy request?

Answer (score 12):

**Worked and Tested**

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const app = express();
app.use('*', createProxyMiddleware({target: 'https://yourdomain.com', changeOrigin: true}));
app.listen(3000);
```

Install the following first

```
npm i -s express
npm i -s http-proxy-middleware
```

Comment: @maruf kindly check this answer

Comment: I made a service/docker out of it
https://github.com/nexys-system/fwd-request