# Node and WordPress routing and setup

Tags: node.js, wordpress

Here's what I'm wanting to do:

I want to run my front-end website with Node, but I want to use WordPress as my blog (self-hosted). Therefore have www.myDomain.com/blog/ use my wordpress posts and such and actually handle the blogging aspect and Node.js handle the rest of the website.

I'm not a WordPress fanboy, but it does blogging pretty well, makes it simple and I would like to be able to have a content creator use it for uploading my posts.

I'm trying to think through alternatives that are not painful, but would really like opinions on this. I'd rather not use a sub-domain for this.

If this seems like a reasonable option, what would the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js serve a wordpress blog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810323/node-js-serve-a-wordpress-blog)

Comment: The short answer to this is, that I Wordpress uses PHP and Node Javascript. So you can't use node to host Wordpress.

Comment: I understand that the following is available: https://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-wordpress. But, am asking more architecturally than for a specific solution. I don't believe this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (assuming that you will have PHP running on the server) would be to:

1. Upload wordpress to www.myDomain.com/blog/
2. During the setup, be sure to select that wordpress will reside at www.myDomain.com/blog/

---

After you do that, everything at or below /blog/ will be handled by Wordpress, and the rest of your website will be pure Node.

Comment: Are there any caveats with DNS (if for instance they are not on the same server) that I should be considering?

Comment: This isn't so much a caveat as a warning that comes out of way too many late nights spent trying to debug my own f-ups, but if I were in your shoes, I would deploy Wordpress first, set the DNS and then test very carefully to make sure that everything at (and below) /blog/ will be served by Wordpress. The goal is to make sure that everything at root and below (with the exception of /blog/) is going to be served by Node. The alternative is some really ugly debugging.