# Install WordPress at www.mysite.com/blog in an angular project

Tags: node.js, wordpress, installation, angular5, subdirectory

I am using Angular 5 and Node.js and I want to install WordPress at /blog of my site. I don't have access to cPanel, and I can't directly access into a subfolder as a route with Angular.

Can somebody provide me a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need some sort of an FTP client + FTP usrname and pass in order to have access to your server. Without these, you cannot do anything

Comment: yeah, i have access to my server. please tell me a way to do it. Thanks!!

Comment: Wordpress out of the box is a PHP application that runs on Apache servers, not node servers. You'll either need to install and run Apache + MySQL or use something like Nginx. See this URL: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/use-nginx-to-run-wordpress-and-node-js it also appears you could use express to server PHP file, see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810323/node-js-serve-a-wordpress-blog if you go with the second link, you'll still need a MySQL database, though.